# Selecting records between specific age range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column (`bday`) which stores user's birthday info.

I searched similar questions and found that one

```
select * from users where datediff(year, bday, getdate()) between 18 and 22;
```

However, when I run this command I get

```
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'
```

What would be the correct way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 1582 is a MySQL error, so presumably you are using MySQL.

The code you probably want is:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.bdate >= curdate() - interval 22 year and
      u.bdate < curdate() - interval 18 year;
```

This isn't exactly equivalent to the SQL Server (or Amazon Redshift) `datediff(year . . . )` function.  That would be more like:

```
select u.*
from users u
where year(u.bdate) - year(curdate()) between 18 and 22;
```

(Note:  There might be an off-by-one error in this calculation.)

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz . . . The first is probably what you intend.  But how is the second "not working"?

Comment: I don't know I got 0 result with second one while first one gives expected results

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz . . . As I say, they are not exactly equivalent.  The first will miss someone born between Oct 20th 2000 and Dec 31 2000, because they are 17.  The second will pick these up.  On the other hand, the second will pick up people who are now 22.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for MariaDB [DATEDIFF](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/datediff/) only takes two arguments:

> `DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)`
>   `expr1` and  `expr2` are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation and it returns (`expr1 – expr2`) expressed as a value in days from one date to the other.

So your query should be:

```
select * from users where datediff(bday,getdate()) between 18 and 22;
```